# While using @KafkaListener, is there a way for it to only get triggered based on a key of a message present in a kafka topic?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, event-listener

The below consumerListener() gets triggered for all messages being sent in the topic 'test_topic', but I would like it to only get triggered if the key of the message in the topic is 'Initiate'.

Currently, I am able to do it as shown below, but is there a better way?

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test_topic", groupId = "group_id")
public void consumerListener(ConsumerRecord<String, MessageModel> message) throws IOException {
    
    if(message.key().equals("Initiate"){
        businessFunctionality(message.value()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Filtering Messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#filtering-messages).

> The Spring for Apache Kafka project also provides some assistance by means of the `FilteringMessageListenerAdapter` class, which can wrap your `MessageListener`. This class takes an implementation of `RecordFilterStrategy` in which you implement the filter method to signal that a message is a duplicate and should be discarded. This has an additional property called `ackDiscarded`, which indicates whether the adapter should acknowledge the discarded record. It is false by default.

> When you use `@KafkaListener`, set the `RecordFilterStrategy` (and optionally ackDiscarded) on the container factory so that the listener is wrapped in the appropriate filtering adapter.

> In addition, a `FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter` is provided, for when you use a batch message listener.

> Starting with version 2.8.4, you can override the listener container factory’s default `RecordFilterStrategy` (if any) by using the `filter` property on the listener annotations.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "filtered", topics = "topic", filter = "differentFilter")
public void listen(Thing thing) {
    ...
}
```